# Typescript typings for protactor in a visual studio project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, protractor

I am writing with protractor e2e tests for our Angular Webapp, since all your javascript code is writtin in typescript i would like to do the same for the tests. Now i have run into the problem that the protractor typescript NuGets are outdated protracotr v1.5.

These are based on the DefinitelyTyped typings, but i cant find them in their offical git repository. So where do i get working Typings?

I cant really get my head around nodejs so if there is a solution including nodejs i am happy to take it but would like to get some detailed explanation.

Errors are like:

> Property 'stacktrace' does not exist on type 'typeof webdriver'

webdriver is defined in the selenium-webdriver.d.ts but apparently it is not complete

Comment: I have no experience with VS, but can't you not just use `npm` instead of NuGet? BTW, it Java*Script* not Java. Totally different things ;)

Comment: Typed java script instead of java (just a space, but i fixed it), i am of course aware of the difference.
However like i said i dont really understand nodejs. i triedto compile with tsc and added dependecys in the package.json. Got the same compile errors visual studio is telling me about.

Comment: Can you add the errors to your question? Maybe we can help you then :) I just know that VS hade issue in the past compiling TS. The typings for protractor are inside the package (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d5d9393da68c6949c92b829d0bba819171c36e5e/package.json#L69) so TypeScript should just pick them up automatically.

Comment: Thank you, i added an error message in my inital post. The link you posted seemed promising but dosent help sind the built folder dosent exit?

Comment: The link was to the repository. This is only the unbuild source. If you install it via npm the `build` folder will be there and you can import/use protractor.

Comment: yes this seems to be what i was looking for. however i still have errors:
> "invalid 'reference' directive syntax" on
> /// <reference types="selenium-webdriver" />
which i think is because it is an typescript 2 instruction. I installed the latest NuGet typescript compiler, but once again dosent help.
> cannot find module 'webdriver-js-extender' on
> import { ExtendedWebDriver } from 'webdriver-js-extender';

sry for all these questions but my colleagues have no idea as well.